# Cedar 2x4 deflection across an 8’ span

Tags: wood

Ran a few calculators but, well, don’t understand the results.

Building a table for a large object shaped somewhat like a Green Egg grill. Design is similar to this:

[Build your own big green egg table](https://www.searedandsmoked.com/diy-big-green-egg-table/)

[image]

Difference is that the table top on mine will have a 96”x28” footprint.

The longitudinal beams are then right at 89”. That seems like a pretty good length to not have center supports in contact with the ground. So is four legs enough here, or should I up it to six or eight? All cedar construction which is light, plus a large BGE, which comes in at around 175lbs.

Comment: I'm migrating this to DIY as I think it's a better fit there.  After reading your question, I don't believe that you're interested in the actual equations as much as you are in learning about someone's similar experience.

Comment: In case OP does really want to do some (simple) lookups and algebra, here is the equation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deflection_(engineering)#Uniformly-loaded_simple_beams If you need help figuring out how to look up the inputs, we can certainly help.

Answer (score 1):

If you were planning on a single front rail you can expect substantial sag over time. The cedar would probably deflect 1/4" to 1/2" initially, but will continue to deform for the first several months.

I'd install at least one additional rail behind the front one, probably using pressure treated pine. A 4x4 wouldn't be excessive. Be sure to crown all rails upward.

Alternatively you could screw a full length 1/4" by 3" aluminum plate to the back of the cedar rail using pairs of 1/4" by 1-1/4" lag screws at 12" intervals.

If you don't like that plan a single leg fastened well to the front rail should do, or extend the two shelf support verticals to the ground, notching around the front rail.